# Print only the Current Value of an array or array index

Tags: java

**Java Novice:**

I am using a for loop to iterate an array and check it's values.
For example: If the array contains the number 100. Then do something,
However if it doesn't then  get the current value of the current variable.

Is it possible to get the value of the current variable when the check was made?

Currently, when I print using the else I get everything printed out.

Like this:

```
1
2
3
Found Something!
```

Please forgive my ignorance. Just experimenting:

```
public class MyArrayExample {

    private int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 100};

    public int[] getArrayValues() {
        return intArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyArrayExample example = new  MyArrayExample();

        int[] arrayValues = example.getArrayValues();

        for(int counter=0; counter<arrayValues.length; counter++) {

            int current = arrayValues[counter];

            if(current == 100)
            {
                System.out.println("Found Something!");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(current);
            }

        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can do it, have you executed your code?

Comment: Its should work fine,dnt see any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of *current* when the check was made, declare it outside the for loop in order to have the access to the variable value and add a boolean flag isFound:

```
    int current = 0;
    boolean isFound = false;

    for(int counter=0; counter<arrayValues.length; counter++) {

        current = arrayValues[counter];

        if(current == 100)
        {
            isFound = true;
            // do something
        }

    }
```

Then once the check is made you can get the value of *current* or print that found something:

```
    if (isFound) {
        System.out.println("Found Something!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("current: " + current);
    }
```

Note. If the value you are looking for is not present in the array, *current* is always assigned with the last value in the array.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to understand: Thank you so much for explaining and providing an example: So the evaluation has to occur outside of the for loop so that only the current value is printed.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition - you don't even have to write a loop yourself, you can just use existing array/collection methods, for example:

> ```
>     Integer[] intArray = new Integer[] {1, 2, 3, 100};
>     List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(intArray);
>     System.out.println(myList.contains(100)); // checks if 100 exists in your array
>     System.out.println(myList.indexOf(100));  // shows the position of the element 100
> ```

Comment: And where is printing of all items not equal to 100?

Comment: @Gangnus: That's why I said "as an addition", because I thought it might help the OP to use his array in that regard.